# mathematica unduloid and nodoid plotting

Tags: plotting

is there anyone who can help me plot this? I am currently using Wolfram Cloud but it doesn't allow me to plot these codes. I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

```
y[s_, B_] := (1 + B*B + 2*B*Sin[s]) ^(1/2) 
x[s_, B_] := Integrate [(1 + B*Sin[t] )/y [ t , B] , { t , 0, s}]
undulary = ParametricPlot[{x[s, 0.5 ], y [s , 0.5 ]}, { s , 0, 4*Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100]
Show[undulary, AxesLabel -> { "x ", "y "}, AspectRatio -> 1 /2.9 , PlotRange -> {0 , 4}]



y[s_] := (1 + 1/4 + Sin[s])^(1/2)
soli = NDSolve[{X'[s] == (1 + Sin[s]/2)/y[s] ,X[0]==0},{X}, {s , -4 Pi, 4 Pi}][[1]]
x[s_] := X[s] /.sol1;
c[s] = {x[s] , y[s]};
p2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x[s] , y[s]Cos[u], y[s]Sin[u]},
{s , 0, 3 Pi}, {u, Pi, 2 Pi},
PlotPoints->100, AspectRatio->Automatic,
Boxed->False, Axes->False]


y[s_, B_] := (1 + B*B + 2*B*Sin[s])^(1/2)
x[s_, B_] := Integrate[(1 + B*Sin[t])/y[t, B] , { t , 0, s}]
nodary = ParametricPlot[{x[s, 2], y[s, 2]}, {s , 0, 5*Pi},
AxesLabel ->{ "x ", "y"}, PlotPoints -> 100]
Show[nodary, AxesLabel -> { "x ", "y "} , AspectRatio -> 1 /1.9 ,
PlotRange -> {0 , 3.5}]


y[ s] := (1 + 4 + 4 Sin[s] )^(l/2 )
soi1 = NDSolvet{X'[s] == (1 + 2 Sin[s])/y [s] , X[0] == 0 }, {X },
{s , 0, 6 Pi}][[1]]
x[s_] := X[s] /.sol1;
c[s_] = {x[s], y [s]} ;
p2 = ParametricPlot3D [{x [s] , y[s] Cos[u], y[s] Sin[u]},
{s , 0, 5 Pi}, {u, Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100,
AspectRatio -> Automatic, Boxed -> False,
Axes -> False]
p3 = ParametricPlot3D [{x [s] , y[s] Cos[u], y[s] Sin[u]},
{s , 0, 5 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints->100,
AspectRatio->Automatic, Boxed -> False,
Axes -> False]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equations from your version are messy, so instead I'll use the parametric equations for the Delaunay curve from [here](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/delaunay/delaunay.shtml) to construct the corresponding [surface of revolution](https://mathcurve.com/surfaces.gb/delaunay/delaunay.shtml) (that is, the unduloid corresponding to the elliptic Delaunay curve, and the nodoid corresponding to the hyperbolic Delaunay curve):

```
(* unduloid *)
With[{a = Sqrt[2], b = 1}, (* semiaxes of the generating ellipse *)
     ParametricPlot3D[{b EllipticE[t, 1 - a^2/b^2] -
                       Sqrt[((a^2 - b^2) (a - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] Cos[t]))/
                            (a + Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] Cos[t])] Sin[t], 
                       b Sqrt[(a - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] Cos[t])/
                              (a + Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] Cos[t])] Cos[u], 
                       b Sqrt[(a - Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] Cos[t])/
                              (a + Sqrt[a^2 - b^2] Cos[t])] Sin[u]},
                      {t, 0, 4 π}, {u, -π, π/2}]]
```

[image: unduloid]

```
(* nodoid *)
With[{a = 1, b = 1}, (* semiaxes of the generating hyperbola *)
     ParametricPlot3D[{b EllipticE[t, -(a^2/b^2)] - b EllipticF[t, -(a^2/b^2)] - 
                       a Sqrt[(Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] - a Cos[t])/
                              (Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] + a Cos[t])] Sin[t], 
                       b Sqrt[(Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] - a Cos[t])/
                              (Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] + a Cos[t])] Cos[u], 
                       b Sqrt[(Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] - a Cos[t])/
                              (Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] + a Cos[t])] Sin[u]},
                      {t, 0, 4 π}, {u, -π, π/2}]]
```

[image: nodoid]

Answer (score 3):

J.M.'s approach is much preferable, but your code can be easily improved:

- Use numerical integration ([`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)) rather than attempting symbolic integration at every step ([`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html)). See [this FAQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/27951) for the reason why I added `NumericQ` to the definition of $x$.
- You don't need to use 100 `PlotPoints`:
  that's painfully slow and it does not improved the quality much.
- You also don't need to use `Show`: you can include all the options you need directly inside the `ParametricPlot` call.

```
ClearAll[x, y]
y[s_, B_] := (1 + B*B + 2*B*Sin[s])^(1/2)
x[s_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(1 + B*Sin[t])/y[t, B], {t, 0, s}]

undulary = 
 ParametricPlot[
   {x[s, 1/2], y[s, 1/2]},
   {s, 0, 4*Pi}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x ", "y "}, AspectRatio -> 1/3
 ]
```

[image: undulary plot]

```
nodary = 
 ParametricPlot[
   {x[s, 2], y[s, 2]}, 
   {s, 0, 5*Pi}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"x ", "y"}, AspectRatio -> 1/2
 ]
```

[image: nodary plot]